# Преобразовать Hashmap в Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Нужно преобразовать Hashmap в Arraylist.Но мне важны не только Value но и Key.Записать их нужно в Arraylist через `/--/`. То есть так: `Key/--/Value`. Хочу сделать это методом.

```
public ArrayList<String> HashmapToArraylist(HashMap<Integer,String> hash) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    //здесь код преобразования
    return al;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return hash.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .map(e -> e.getKey() + "/--/" + e.getValue())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Для древних версий Java:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = hash.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.next();
    al.add(entry.getKey() + "/--/" + entry.getValue());
}
return al;
```

Comment: Ошибка Unknown method 'stream'...

Comment: @LeonidAltshooler у вас Java 7 или более старая?

Comment: Я не знаю.Наверно да.

Comment: Есть вариант для java 7?